# How to debug response from external server?

Tags: php, apache, debugging, xdebug

I would like to be able to debug my application when it's receiving response from external server.

I'm integrating my application with online payments systems like PayPal and PayU.
Payment confirmation is made in background by POST method send to my PHP script from PayPal server for example, independently of browser. I have my development machine with static IP with Apache and Xdebug installed.

How to start remote debug session without browser?

Are there any other options to debug and test online payment integration ?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that I can set xDebug to start automatically by :

xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

in Your php.ini ( similar problem was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531391/launch-xdebug-in-netbeans-on-an-external-request))

but I still have feeling that I'm in stone Age:
setting remote_autostart = 1 and restarting apache every time I need to start working on handlind external request isn't something difficult but there must be something better than that.