# How to show the Apache2 (PHP) logs in Netbeans

Tags: php, ubuntu, logging, netbeans, apache2

I used to work with Apache Tomcat and was always satisfied with the output of server logs and errors in my Netbeans IDE.
Now I'd like to do something in PHP with Apache2 (Ubuntu).

But how is it possible to configure Netbeans to display Apache2-Logs? It doesn't seem to be possible to add the Apache2 as a server and neither has Options-->PHP anything related to this issue.

By trial and error after programming a few errors in my code the output-window still remains empty...

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansAndWebStack#Testing_the_Apache_Web_Server_from_the_NetBeans_IDE

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Comment: I found it already but wasn't sure if it's what I'm looking for. xDebug didn't ring a bell and there seems to be a strong focus on Zend (as said I'm mostly a Java-guy and haven't done much in PHP for years. I have no idea what Zend is). Thanks to the both of you, I'll need a while to read through it.

Comment: Some extra-work was necessary... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613726/netbeans-shows-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug