# Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, windows-7, xdebug

I am using Windows7 of 64 BIT. My PHP version is 5.6.3 (got this using phpinfo();). I am trying to use **XDebug** with **NetBeans**. My Netbeans version is 8.0.2. My **Xdebug** section of phpinfo(); is as below.

[image]

I placed below code in php.ini file and restarted Apache as well.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "D:\XAMPP\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\XAMPP\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.5
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:\XAMPP\tmp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

I set a Breakpoint in my code of Netbeans. I am getting **Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)** at the bottom of Netbeans while I click on Debug project button.

Could any one know where is the problem ??

Comment: try `xdebug.remote_host=localhost` if netbeans runs on the machine with IP `192.168.1.5` In Netbeans Set the url to `http://localhost/myproject/index.php` . also on localhost remove `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`.

Comment: My Comment could help you? any response to my comment?

Comment: For me, I didn't know that there were THREE locations where I had to specify port = 9000, and the mismatch was causing “Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)”: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41768167/470749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have it setup, I assume you checked all the usual suspects:

- Config
- Remote host
- idkey

and so on.

Two things that I tend to forget are:

1. Select Web Root folder for the project
2. Make sure your code in Netbeans and on the server is the same. (Just
   download the project again)