# XDebug not establishing connection in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

My XDebug extension is not establishing its connection with netbeans. Following are the settings which i have placed in php.ini file:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost:8080"
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

Please help me in figuring out the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `xdebug.remote_connect_back` is commented out

Answer (score 0):

To debug your php code in Netbeans IDE you should enable `XDebug` in Netbeans. To do that goto `Tools` - `Options` there select `PHP` tab and ensure that Debugging port and session ID matching with your `XDebug` configuration in `php.ini` file. After that click on OK.

Change your `php.ini` file like this.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"  <--- here
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

And restart your Apache server [XAMPP or WAMP].

If this solution not working goto
`localhost` in your browser select PHP version tab right click select all and copy the contents and paste it [here](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php). If you have old version of `XDebug` then download the latest `php_xdebug.dll` file. Copy it to `C:\xampp\php\ext\` directory and it's done.

Comment: I have tried your solution Netbeans cant connect to xdebug it keeps connecting forever.

Comment: Check this [Stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613726/netbeans-shows-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug) and [this](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/netbeans-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug-issue)

Comment: oh! it worked finally. thankx. i only copy pasted your settings. forgot to add port=9000. thank you it is working.