# Xdebug with NetBeans Linux Mint stops at waiting for connection

Tags: php, nginx, netbeans, xdebug, linux-mint

Can't get Xdebug work with NetBeans on PC with Linux Mint and nginx.

I've installed Xdebug as recommended in https://xdebug.org/wizard.php.

In `php.ini` I now have lines - tried many combinations mainly from [netbeans shows "Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613726/netbeans-shows-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug), but result is always the same: debugging in NetBeans ends with waiting for connection (nebeans-xdebug)

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_log = "/home/pop/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_port=9002
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
;xdebug.remote_host=10.251.4.140
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
;xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
```

Xdebug section from `php -i` is now (port on NetBeans is currently set to 9002)

```
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => netbeans-xdebug => netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => On => On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 127.0.0.1 => 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log => /home/pop/xdebug.log => /home/pop/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9002 => 9002
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => On => On
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

xdebug.log - strange that there are logs only every half hour

```
Log opened at 2017-08-15 10:09:01
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9001.
W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9001', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-08-15 10:09:01

Log opened at 2017-08-15 10:39:01
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000. :-|
W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-08-15 10:39:01

Log opened at 2017-08-15 11:09:01
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9002. :-|
W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9002', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-08-15 11:09:01
```

[Netbeans xdebug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu1NK.png)

Comment: Add screenshot of your XDebug config in Netbeans

Comment: Tarun Lalwani: added (the bottom of the question)

Comment: Change  `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0` also `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0`. And i hope both are running the same machines? No VMs, no containers

Comment: Changed Change xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0 with no results, but why you have written it twice. Was it a typo? Yes, no VMs or containers.

Comment: Sorry the other one was meant to be `xdebug.remote_connect_back=0`

Comment: Thanks, but no progress

Comment: See if the logs have changed now?

Comment: Now are all logs similar to first one: Log opened at 2017-08-18 11:39:01
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9002.
W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9002', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-08-18 11:39:01

Comment: These should have gone from logs now `I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.` ??

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry can't make new lines in comments to increase readability.

Comment: Hard to tell without debugging

Comment: How you can debug such problem?

Comment: Can you try downloading PhpStorm and checking if their debugger works?

Comment: Thank you, finally got it, there was a mess with different php versions on PC