# Xdebug with CodeIgniter and NetBeans

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, xdebug

I've installed Xdebug on Ubuntu serve rand I've set `/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-xdegug.ini` file this way

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.0.140
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
```

`remote_host` is an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine on the same local network that my computer.

When I try to start the debugging NetBeans has a message on bottom `waiting for connection (netbeans-debug)` and the execution doesn't stop on the breakpoint.

I'm using CodeIgniter and the URL is launched with `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug` parameter added to the URL.

I'm not sure about which `php.ini` I have to modify:

```
/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
```

or

```
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [netbeans shows "Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613726/netbeans-shows-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug)

Comment: 1) *"I'm not sure about which `php.ini` I have to modify"* If it's web page debug -- then the that used by Apache. You can use `phpinfo()` and in top table it shows what php.ini file is used etc. 2) *"remote_host is an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine"* WHY? Can you clarify that moment? That has to be an IP of where NetBeans is running ... as it;s Xdebug that connects to IDE and not other way around. 3) Other than that -- collect xdebug log to see what is happening from that end.