# Breakpoints are not executed on PHP application

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I'm trying to debug a PHP CodeIgniter app but the breakpoints are not executed, its a remote project I connect by FTP with NetBeans and Xdebug is running.

At `xdebug_remote.log` file  I get the following:

```
<- breakpoint_set -i 138 -t line -s enabled -f file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/MyApp/application/controllers/Public/Home.php -n 15
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="138" state="enabled" id="17240001"></response>
```

It's possible that the breakpoints are set on local files instead on remote file and that the reason because breakpoints are not working?

Comment: Instead of creating new tickets with updates .. why not just provide them in original ticket at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288753/xdebug-with-codeigniter-and-netbeans ?

Comment: If it's a remote code .. then you most likely have not provided the path mapping ... so NetBeans is unable to map local file to remote. Check your NetBeans settings for that (cannot say where as I do not use NetBeans myself).