# NetBeans shows "waiting for connection" when starting Xdebug

Tags: netbeans, wamp, xdebug, xdebug-3

Apologies for raising yet another query about this issue but none of the existing information in SO and elsewhere that I've been able to find have helped to resolve my problem. I'm familiar with the environment and have previously installed it successfully. This time I'm completely at a loss.

I've installed WAMP server 3.2.6 under Windows 11 x64 with PHP 7.4.26, Xdebug 3.1.1 and NetBeans 12.6.

My php.ini settings are

```ini
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.26/zend_ext/php_xdebug-3.1.1-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=http://127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
```

NetBeans settings:

```
Debugger port: 9003
Session ID: netbeans-xdebug
Stop at First Line: checked
Resolve breakpoints: checked
```

`phpinfo()` and `xdebug_info()` run from within WAMP server indicate that the Xdebug module is loaded. I've disabled virus checking and firewall. PHP and NetBeans logs show nothing.

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: 1) Enable [Xdebug log](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#log), confirm it's enabled and try to debug -- it will show what Xdebug does. 2) `xdebug.client_host=http://127.0.0.1` this should be either domain or IP and NOT an URL. Just `127.0.0.1` will do. 3) `xdebug.start_with_request=trigger` try with `yes` instead of `trigger` -- this will tell Xdebug to try to debug every single request regardless of the "debug me" flag presence. Once you have it working, you can change it back.

Comment: @LazyOne: Many thanks. After your changes, WAMP rewrote a php.ini line to "xdebug.client_host=localhost". On clicking on Debug project in Netbeans, the browser appeared with the URL "http://localhost/tvcdev/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug". This doesn't exist - the correct URL is "http://tvcdev.local/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug". If I type this into the browser, the correct index page comes up and Netbeans' xdebug flag changes to "running" with a break on the first line of code. How do I resolve this, as the virtual host is obviously set and working?

Comment: I'm not using WAMP or NetBeans myself. All my comments are for **Xdebug config in php.ini** and not for your IDE/web server. Therefore I suggest you revert your changes made in NetBeans and/or WAMP.

Comment: [1] Although [netbeans shows "Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17613726/2985643) is an old question, and some of it may be out of date, there is a lot of information in the comments and answers. It might be worth a look if you haven't already seen it. [2] Please update your question based on the new information in the comments, including your revised `xdebug.start_with_request` and `xdebug.client_host` settings. All information should be in the question itself - it should not be necessary to read any comments to properly understand your current concern.