# PHP Netbeans breakpoints only hit for requests from debug session initiated browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, xdebug

I am debugging a PHP codeigniter project where there is a controller method to read the `php://input` and get the data from it. I have put a breakpoint in there and it will successfully hit, if I request the method via browser (Which is started by the netbeans debug). I have another JAVA application that sends the data to same method. What I need is to capture that. But netbeans breakpoints does not hit by the requests initiated by the java application. Is there anyway I can achive this ? Thanks in advance.

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few researches and tweaks I was able to configure this. First you need to add

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
```

to php.ini to auto start the debug session without `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug` and Netbeans only listen to above ide key in default.

Then you should enable Do not open web browser in Project Properties -> Run Configuration -> Advance. No path mapping needed for me (I enabled the option to copy files to server). Now breakpoints should hit request initiated by any source (For me Firefox, Chrome and my Java app).

**Reference:**

[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531391/launch-xdebug-in-netbeans-on-an-external-request)

[Xdebug docs](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote)